# I cannot change datadir of mysql in windows

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am trying to change the datadir a mysql installation (of xampp) to put it in a cloud directory like dropbox o Google Drive a development database.

The steps followed by me are these:

- Sutdown the mysql server.
- Copy all files and dir from C:\xampp\mysql\data and put them in my cloud dir (C:\users\Dani\Google Driver_web_development\web-mysql-databases)
- Open `my.ini` file on `c:\xampp\mysql\bin\` and change these variables:

  datadir = "C:/Users/Dani/Google Drive/_web_development/web-mysql-databases"
  by
  datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"

  innodb_data_home_dir = "C:/Users/Dani/Google Drive/_web_development/web-mysql-databases"
  by
  innodb_data_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"

  innodb_log_group_home_dir = "C:/Users/Dani/Google Drive/_web_development/web-mysql-databases"
  by
  innodb_log_group_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"

  plugin_dir = "C:/Users/Dani/Google Drive/_web_development/web-mysql-databases/lib/plugin/" 
  by
  plugin_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
- Save the changes and launch up the service again.
- MYSQL cannot stay running.

Note: When i put all files in its original place (`c:\xampp\mysql\data`), all works fine. And no log is produced in my data directory.

How can i do?

Comment: Try to start the service from the command line and report the error message. Does mysql has write access to the cloud directory? And I assume that plugin_dir should not be set to the data directory.

Answer (score 1):

For all the people with the same problem.

This does not work if mysql stuff is on Google Drive folders, i dont know why. In other hand, this works with Dropbox folders for example.

Answer (score 0):

I my case, Windows 7 and MySQL 5.5, it worked when I changed the permissions to the Google Drive folder. I gave the same permissions as the ones for the Dropbox folder, indeed some users were missing in Google Drive, e.g. SYSTEM.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but this could help.

I guess the problem is in the space in "Google Drive" folder name, I did the same thing but with GoogleDrive as folder name and it worked.